# Sed to replace previous line

Tags: sed

I am trying to replace the previous line of a string match.

Example json

```
  "test" : {
    "aa" : true,
    "ac" : "port",
    "tr" : "p2",
    "ll" : 90,
    "mp" : true
  }
```

If "ll" equals 90, I need to change the previous line to "mu" : "p1". I have tried the below sed but it always replaces the same line instead on the previous line. Please suggest

```
sed -e '/"ll" : 90/!b;!N;c"mu" : "p1"'
```

Comment: If you show your complete JSON object, somebody can show you how to do it with a proper JSON parser such as jq instead of something brittle like sed.

Comment: Agree with @BenjaminW. here, recommend using `JSON` aware tools like `jq` for manipulating json text files.

Answer (score 2):

You can try this `sed`:

```
sed 'N;/\n *"ll" : 90/{s/^\([^"]*\).*\n/\1"mu" : "p1",\n/;};P;D' file
```

As suggested by @potong,

```
sed -r 'N;s/.*(\n(\s*)"ll" : 90,)/\2"mu : "p1",\1/;P;D' file
```

Output:

```
"test" : {
  "aa" : true,
  "ac" : "port",
  "mu" : "p1",
  "ll" : 90,
  "mp" : true
}
```

Comment: Since the substitution is integral to the match a single command is that is needed, perhaps `sed -r 'N;s/.*(\n(\s*)"ll" : 90,)/\2"mu : "p1",\1/;P;D' file` might do the job.